# Transferring money from Foreign Account to NRO Account in india - is it taxable?

Tags: income-tax, india, non-resident, foreign-income

I'm working in Maldives.

1. I'm transferring money from my Maldives savings account to my Indian
   Savings account(NRO). **Will it be taxable in India?**
2. Again I'm transferring the money from my Indian savings acccount to
   my dad's Indian savings account. **Will it be taxable?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taxability does not depending on transfer of money to NRO. It depending on your tax status in India. Assuming you have spent more than 182 days outside India for the financial year 1 April 2015 to 31 March 2016, you would be NRI.

> I am transferring money from my Maldives saving account to my Indian Saving account(NRO). Will it be taxable in India?

Assuming you are NRI, this is not taxable. Any interest in NRO account is taxable in India.

> Again I am transferring the money from my Indian savings account to my dad's Indian saving account. Will it be taxable?

This is not taxable to you. To your father it would be treated as Gift. As per Gift tax, this is not taxable to your father as well. If the amount is large, keep proper documentation of the transaction.

Any income that is generated i.e. interest etc on this amount will be taxable to your father.

Comment: I assume that any interest generated on monies transferred to the OP's NRO account (held in India) will be subject to Indian income tax even though the OP is an NRI and might even attract Maldives income tax, possibly subject to any Double Taxation Avoidance Agreements or Tax Treaties between the Maldives and India? The reason for asking is that you mention taxation of the interest generated in the father's account but do not say anything about tax liability of the interest in the OP's NRO account.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Agreed. Edited the answer to reflect this.